# 'adb devices' find my usb device,but android studio not. only show "Loading Devices", also say when run "no target device found"

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, manjaro, usb-debugging

I am use android studio 4.1 with manjaro linux. I want run app with usb debug,I am setup my mobile(oreo 8.1) for usb debug(developer mode-->usb debugging).
[image: check image]
you see in this image my problem.

'adb devices' result in terminal show's device. but not recognized in android studio,it show only "Loading Devices". when i try to run this, it say "no target device found".

can anyone know it's solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command in Android Studio terminal

> adb kill-server

after that run this command

> adb start-server

Comment: I forget to install some SDK platform-tools.